# "ERROR ITMS-90029" Storyboard file LaunchScreen~ipad.storyboardc was not found

Tags: xamarin, storyboard

I have a Xamarin Forms project which debugs fine, builds fine on both iOS and Android. However when building the IPA for iOS, I try to use the Application Loader to submit the IPA and it reveals the error below:

I am getting the error "ERROR ITMS-90029" Storyboard file 'LaunchScreen~ipad.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename.

I have configured the LaunchScreen.storyboard file to "Builds for" iOS 8.0 and later.

As it's a Xamarin Forms project, I only have one storyboard file, LaunchScreen.storyboard . In my Info.plist, my Deployment Info is:

- Deployment Target: 7.0

  Devices: Universal

  Main Screen: LaunchScreen

  Device Orientations: Portrait, Upside Down

  Hide Status bar: no

  Requires full screen: no

Launch Images:

- Launch Screen: LaunchScreen

This is such an absolute nightmare. I have tried every combination of settings, rebuilding, cleaning, you name it. They all produce IPA successfully, and they all error out with the same error. I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this breaks on EVERY build. The solution is, after EVERY build, to manually edit the Info.plist with a text editor and add the following key/value combos. They either disappear with each build, or they add back in spurious values:

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
<string></string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by re-selecting the Storyboard from the dropdowns in info.plist options. Make sure to re-select the option from BOTH **Deployment Info > Main Interface** and **Launch Images > Launch Screen**.

NOTE: I fixed this in Visual Studio Mac. I haven't tried the same in VS Windows.